# Prove $o(u^{-1})=o(u)$ for all $u \in G$ and $o(uh)=o(hu)$ for all $u,h \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $g \in G-\{1_G\}$.

Prove $o(u^{-1})=o(u)$ for all $u \in G$ and $o(uh)=o(hu)$ for all $u,h \in G$.

Let $n=o(u)$. Then $u^n=1$ and so 1$=u^nu^{-n}=u^{-n}=(u^{-1})^n$ so $o(u^{-1})|n$. How do I show $n|o(u^{-1})$?

For the second bit I am not sure.

Comment: What is the purpose of $g \in G - \{1_G\}$?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't needed for this part of the question

Comment: You showed that $o(u^{-1}) | o(u)$ for all $u\in G$. Well $u^{-1} \in G$, so $o((u^{-1})^{-1}) | o(u^{-1})$, but $(u^{-1})^{-1} = u$! So by symmetry $o(u) | o(u^{-1})$ too.

Comment: [Is it true that the order of $ab$ is always equal to the order of $ba$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238212/is-it-true-that-the-order-of-ab-is-always-equal-to-the-order-of-ba) and [An element of a group has the same order as its inverse](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008610/an-element-of-a-group-has-the-same-order-as-its-inverse).

Comment: I don't get the bit after so $(o(u^{-1})^{-1})$

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Claim}$: $\quad o(u) = o(u^{-1})$ for all $u \in G$.

$\textbf{Proof}$:

Let $u \in G$.

Let $n = o(u)$ and $m = o(u^{-1})$.

Then $1 = 11 = u^n (u^{-1})^m$.

If $n>m$, then $1 = u^{n-m}$, which cannot be since $o(u) = n$.

If $n<m$, then $1 = (u^{-1})^{m-n}$, which cannot be since $o(u^{-1}) = m$.

So it can be concluded that $n = m$.

$\textbf{Claim}$: $\quad o(uh) = o(hu)$ for all $u,h = G$.

$\textbf{Proof}$:

Let $u,h \in G$.

Let $n = o(uh)$ and $m = o(hu)$.

Then $hu = h(uh)^nu = (hu)^nhu \Rightarrow (hu)^n = 1$. So $m|n$.

Similarly, $uh = u(hu)^mh = (uh)^muh \Rightarrow (uh)^m= 1$. So $n|m$.

Therefore $n = m$.

Comment: How did $h(uh)^nu$ turn into $(hu)^nhu$?

Comment: For the first one is there anything I can do to my solution? In the solutions it said by symmetry $n|o(u^{-1})$ but I don't see it.

Comment: To see why try it with $n = 3$, so $h(uh)^3u = h(uhuhuh)u = (huhuhu)hu = (hu)^3hu$, now convince yourself that it works for any $n$.

Comment: Why can you move the elements?

Comment: No elements are moving, the brackets are just in different places.

Comment: I see it thanks