# For square matrices $ (AB)^k=I_n$ for some $k$ implies $(BA)^k=I_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ square real matrices.

> Suppose $(AB)^k=I_n$ for some $k$ then $(BA)^k=I_n$

I know the result holds for $k=1$. I believe this should be easy but I cannot see it. Any ideas?

Comment: How would you show it for $k=1$? With a little luck, that proof can be generalized with only minor adjustments.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/238212/42969 – found quickly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(A%20B)%5Ek%20%3D%20I_n%24)

Comment: @MartinR: oof cannot believe I forgot that result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to prove that $B$ is invertible. To do this, suppose that $B$ is not invertible, i.e. $Bx = 0$ for some non-zero vector $x$, and try to arrive at a contradiction. There might be an easier way to do this too.

Then, take the equation $(AB)^k = I_n$, i.e. $$\underbrace{ABAB\cdots ABAB}_{k \ AB\text{'s}} = I_n$$ and multiply both sides by $B$ on the left and $B^{-1}$ on the right. What do you get?

Comment: Thank you very much, it was easy!